# WPF: Expander binding in Listview

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to ListView with expander including some of information. So, I made this code. I'm not sure binding expander like that is correct. I just try to Binding like ListViewItem, But when I try to expander is not work at all. Here is my code.

XAML :

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <ListView x:Name="lv">
            <ListView.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <HeaderedItemsControl>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </HeaderedItemsControl>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListView.Template>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LogBase}">
                    <Expander Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> <!-- why this code is not wokring...? -->
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding No}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Timestamp}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                    </Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

code behind :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<LogBase> logs { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        logs = new List<LogBase>();

        logs.Add(new LogBase()
        {
            No = "1",
            Timestamp = "123456789",
            Type = "Tcp"
        });

        logs.Add(new LogBase()
        {
            No = "2",
            Timestamp = "123456789",
            Type = "Tcp"
        });

        logs.Add(new LogBase()
        {
            No = "3",
            Timestamp = "123456789",
            Type = "Tcp"
        });


        lv.ItemsSource = logs;

        DataContext = this;
    }

}

public class LogBase
{
    public string No { get; set; }
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

for better understanding I captured what I want to

[Now my program's situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmS3T.png)

If you have any of opinions please comment for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to bind the header to set the `DataContext` of the `HeaderTemplate` correct. This is done by `Header="{Binding HeaderSource}"`. In your case just use `Header="{Binding}"` to bind directly to the item:

```
<Expander Header="{Binding}>
```

After that your code works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you so much... I feel like under cloud. what was I missing... But.. just answer was Header="{Bining}"..

Comment: Can you answer why header is not binding Listview.ItemTemplate as default? I couldn't find in MSDN in expander

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242734/what-does-exactly-expander-header-binding-do